# React Native Push Notifications, FCM says token is invalid on iOS only (Android works)

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a React Native App which is trying to send push notifications using the Firebase Cloud Messaging Service. We are testing this using Insomnia.

To do this, we are using a package called “react-native-push-notification” by zo0r.
We’ve been able to obtain an iOS apn token from a real-life apple device. We are then able to successfully send a POST request to this URL:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport
```

to convert the apns token into a registration token for Google’s firebase cloud messaging platform.

However, when we try and send a message using the converted token, by sending a POST request to this endpoint:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

using this JSON payload:

```
{
   "direct_book_ok": true,
    "to": "fTiQ5mg266o:APA91bGQN1s9sYJh9U_B6h1vuwAjpQVrPIJFnCWWsiv4PgKTCOCqLiKIdAD6ls48f-dBbnV3tOdc6NvTScXSRJYrXNHz_5QonSFraEau5jKSJPcw8HYeOb2YnutC39TlaIlKBnD3FpSx",
     "notification": {
                       "title": "Breaking News",
                        "body": "New Story available."
              },
     "priority": "high"
}
```

AND these headers:

```
Authorization: key=<OUR_SECRET_KEY> 
and 
Content-Type: application/json
```

The Google API responds with the following error, indicating that the notification has failed because of an “invalid argument”.

```
{
 "multicast_id": 3503657462083604439,
 "success": 0,
 "failure": 1,
 "canonical_ids": 0,
 "results": [
   {
     "error": "InvalidParameters: RpcError:INVALID_ARGUMENT"
   }
 ]
}
```

How would we remedy this? We’ve tried both sandbox=true and sandbox false.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the legacy API and not v1?

Comment: I have tried the newer api with the same result. I am happy to use either.

Comment: Could you test the corrected version in my answer below?  Remember that the legacy API and v1 use different authentication tokens, you'll need to mint an OAuth token.

Comment: Indeed, for the newer API I had to generate a bearer token to authenticate. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to *assume* that since you used the v1 IID API to convert the APN token that you need to use the v1 FCM API to send a message.  There's really no reason to continue to use the legacy API.

`POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<ProjectId>/messages:send`

```
{
    "validate_only": false,
    "message": {
        "token": "fTiQ5mg266o:APA91bGQN1s9sYJh9U_B6h1vuwAjpQVrPIJFnCWWsiv4PgKTCOCqLiKIdAD6ls48f-dBbnV3tOdc6NvTScXSRJYrXNHz_5QonSFraEau5jKSJPcw8HYeOb2YnutC39TlaIlKBnD3FpSx",
        "notification": {
            "title": "Breaking News",
            "body": "New Story available."
        },
        "android": {
            "priority": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

[REST API Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send)

Also note that v1 doesn't use a server key like in the legacy API, you need to mint an OAuth token.